# Posso usar um arquivo JSON como banco de dados?

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, json

Estou querendo iniciar um projeto, porém não quero criar um banco de dados então, gostaria de saber se eu poderia usar um arquivo *json* como banco de dados.

Comment: Poder pode, sempre irá depender do seu projeto, estrutura, etc. Se é melhor para você e/ou sua aplicação, claro. Procure sobre "noSql", pra ter uma noção de bancos não relacionais.

Comment: basicamente é isso que o mongodb faz, não é?

Comment: Também tem o [firebase realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/?hl=pt-br), é bem simples e a documentação é simples e completa

Comment: A resposta do @GuilhermeCostamilam atende bem o que você quer. Só não entendo porque fazer isso. =) Na minha visão, com o banco é mais fácil de manipular os dados.

Comment: Depende, se ele tiver um bom conhecimento de javascript e pouco de php, armazenar os dados em formato json e depois atribui-los a uma variável é bem mais simples. O que é bem mais complicado, é migrar de no-sql para sql ou de um banco para outro, no caso, de arquivos para um banco

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam então, mas vamos supor que você vai trabalhar apenas nesse formato (json) criando um CRUD. Não seria mais fácil usar um NoSql? Do que abrir o arquivo, verifica qual é a linha, alterar, etc..

Comment: obs.. Estou perguntando porque eu nunca fiz isso. rsrs

Comment: Sim, seria bem mais simples, pra mim, isso porque já criei aplicações no-sql, mas se apessoa nem sabe direto o que é isso, pode não ser para ela. Não disse que arquivos json é mais simples do que um banco de dados no-sql, porém, também não é, necessariamente, mais difícil. Como eu disse, é mais uma questão de ponto de vista

Comment: basicamente se vc criar funções para facilitar consultas e inserção de dados num json, vc criou um bd nosql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode fazer isso com as funções de arquivo um [exemplo de gravação](http://www.devwilliam.com.br/php/como-ler-e-escrever-no-formato-json-como-php):

```
// Array com dados
$cliente1 = array(
    'codigo'   => '001',
    'nome'     => 'William',
    'telefone' => '012 9999-6352'
);

$cliente2 = array(
    'codigo'   => '002',
    'nome'     => 'Adriano',
    'telefone' => '012 8888-4452'
);

$cliente3 = array(
    'codigo'   => '003',
    'nome'     => 'Maria',
    'telefone' => '013 3434-4444'
);

// Atribui os 3 arrays para apenas um array
$dados = array($cliente1, $cliente2, $cliente3);

// Tranforma o array $dados em JSON
$dados_json = json_encode($dados);

// Cria o arquivo cadastro.json
// O parâmetro "a" indica que o arquivo será aberto para escrita
$fp = fopen("cadastro.json", "a");

// Escreve o conteúdo JSON no arquivo
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);

// Fecha o arquivo
fclose($fp);
```

E um exemplo de [leitura](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fread.php):

```
// Para o PHP 5 e superior
$handle = fopen("cadastro.json", "rb");
$contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);

var_dump(json_decode($contents));
```

Você também pode atribuir o json do arquivo a uma variável do javascript e trabalhar com ela no front-end, nesse caso não use `json_decode`:

```
//...
echo "<script> let json = $contents; </script>";
```

Mas acredito que esteja "pensando errado", se você quer fazer algo mais simples usando um arquivo json para depois não ter que ficar alterando a estrutura do banco, regras de negócio, etc. sugiro que só faça a parte de view, valide ela e então passe para o back-end. Fazer um sistema assim e depois mudar o banco de dados de um arquivo json para um modelo SQL vai dar muito mais trbalho, é preferível manter a mesma estrutura (no-sql), talvez apenas mudando de arquivos json para algum banco como MongoDB ou Firebase Realtime Database

Comment: Trabalhar o json como bd diretamente no javascript seria uma tremenda falha de segurança.

Se for para utilizar o json como bd, deve-se protege-lo de acesso externo e criar no backend as regras para acesso.

Comment: Acredito que não tem problema isso, pelo que entendi, é apenas para iniciar o projeto, a versão final não ficará assim

Answer (score 0):

Os dados de configuração padrão de um módulo do sistema que estou desenvolvendo está sendo salvo em banco .json. Então de um modo geral, sim, você pode usa... Dica 1: se tiver usando PHP, construa uma classe para gerenciar o CRUD dos dados nos arquivos .json utilizados como DB. Dica 2: Crie/edite um .htaccess (ou crie no diretório superior dos arquivos .json), para impedir a listagem de diretórios/arquivos isso evita a listagem dos arquivos .json utilizados como DB. Ainda no .htaccess configure para impedir o acesso a pasta dos arquivos .json ou o acesso direto ao seu arquivo db.json (por exemplo), assim evita que terceiros acesse seu .json diretamente do navegador (por exemplo) e apenas o seu servidor terá acesso ou a sua classe PHP criada anteriormente. Para melhorar a experiencia, faça em AJAX.